# mysqlcheck with --optimize but only for MyISAM Tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database, myisam

I've been reading over http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html in an effort to figure out how to optimize all of my MyISAM tables but can't seem to get it. I found what looked like it would be a hand script but I can't get it to work and I'd rather actually understand it.

This is what I came across:

`for i in mysql -e 'select concat(table_schema,".",table_name) from  information_schema.tables where engine="MyISAM"'; do mysql -e "optimize table $i"; done`

But it would be great to use something more along the lines of what is described in the documentation like `mysqloptimize --all-databases` but I definitely don't want it to try to optimize my InnoDB tables..

Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use stored routines to optimize tables. But, obviously, this requires mysql service to run. A sample of stored routine is shown below. Cursor defined in this procedure selects all tables from within current db (in which this sp is defined). You could add conditions for checking MYISAM tables with condition in WHERE as in example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE util_optimize_all_tables()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE endloop INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tableName CHAR(100);
    DECLARE rCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `TABLE_NAME`
        FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND `ENGINE`='MyISAM';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET endloop = 1;

    OPEN rCursor;
    FETCH rCursor INTO tableName;

    WHILE endloop = 0 DO
        SET @sql = CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE `', tableName, '`;');
        PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE statement;

        FETCH rCursor INTO tableName;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE rCursor;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```